# Use of State hosting to change variable in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change the value of variable in jetpack compose. I am trying to use `Stateful` and `Stateless` with some code, but it have some problem to increment the value. Can you guys guide me on this.

**ItemColorStateful**

```
@Composable
fun ItemColorStateful() {
    var index by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Different Color")
        ButtonScopeStateless(
            index = { index },
            onIndexChange = {
                index = it
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**ButtonScopeStateless**

```
@Composable
fun ButtonScopeStateless(
    index: () -> Int,
    onIndexChange: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    Button(onClick = { onIndexChange(index()++) }) {
        Text(text = "Click Me $index")
    }
}
```

I am getting error on `index()++`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the general pattern for [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) your stateless composable should have two parameters:

- **value**: T: the current value to display
- **onValueChange: (T) -> Unit**: an event that requests the value to change, where T is the proposed new value

In your case:

- `index:  Int`,
- `onIndexChange: (Int) -> Unit`

Also you should respect the *Encapsulated* properties: **Only stateful composables can modify their state. It's completely internal**.
Use `onIndexChange(index+1)` instead of `onIndexChange(index()++)`. In this way the state is modified by the `ItemColorStateful`.

You can use:

```
@Composable
fun ItemColorStateful() {
    var index by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Different Color")
        ButtonScopeStateless(
            index = index ,
            onIndexChange = {
                index = it
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ButtonScopeStateless(
    index:  Int,  //value=the current value to display
    onIndexChange: (Int) -> Unit //an event that requests the value to change, where Int is the proposed new value
) {
    Button(onClick = { onIndexChange(index+1) }) {
        Text(text = "Click Me $index")
    }
}
```

Comment: In `ButtonScopeStateless` in first parameter  `index: () -> Int` why did you change to `index:  Int`. I see in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWBN0y0lFNY) they mention to use lambda to avoid recomposition. So in these we don't need that?

Comment: @VivekModi The example in the video is quite different. *When you are passing frequently changing State variables into modifiers, you should use the lambda versions of the modifiers whenever possible.*. They are using an `offset` modifier with a value related to a scroll gesture (`val scroll = rememberScrollState(0)`). In your case you are just updating a simple value (not a modifier).

Comment: Ok got it now. Thank you so much....

Answer (score 0):

**ItemColorStateful**

```
    @Composable
    fun ItemColorStateful() {
    var index by remember { mutableStateOf(-1) }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Different Color")
        ButtonScopeStateless(
            index = index ,
            onIndexChange = {
                index++
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**ButtonScopeStateless**

```
@Composable
fun ButtonScopeStateless(
    index: Int,
    onIndexChange: () -> Unit,
) {
    Button(onClick = {
        onIndexChange()
    }) {
        Text(text = "Click Me $index")
    }
}
```